# mandatory parameter in Oracle BI Publisher 10g

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

Can we define a parameter to be mandatory so that user needs to enter some value for it in Oracle BI Publisher 10g? If yes, how do we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue days before. It seems that BI publisher do not support such kind of constraint on parameters. To solve this issue, we had to connect to BI publisher using its web services, get the report parameters and import the report into our application. Using this way, we managed to set any kind of constraint on parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. The best you can do is to show an alert message in the blank report (which should be empty) saying "The field `xyz` is a required field".

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the report from Oracle concurrent manager then you can make any/all parameters required in the concurrent program definition.